# Voltage signal significantly drops when BNC cable is connected

Tags: impedance-matching

I've built the following photodetecting circuit in photoconductive mode:

[image]

For Alligator-BNC RG58 coaxial cable, I use [this product](http://eleparts.co.kr/EPX33HV8) (the web site is in Korean, so you might not able to read it.)

When I probe a voltage across a resistor `R3` with an oscilloscope while a switch `S1` is open, I got the following yellow line:

[image]

Blue is the reference signal (HIGH: LED ON, LOW: LED OFF)

If I close the switch, the voltage drops significantly and I got the following:

[image]

I suspect that this is because of impedance mismatch.

However, I have no idea to solve the impedance mismatch problem since I have little knowledge about circuit.

In short,

- Is this an impedance mismatch problem?
- If it is, how can I solve it?
- If it is not, what is a problem of it?
- And how can I solve it?

Comment: After I posted this question. Something comes into my head. I think that `R3` is 47k, and `RG58` is 50. Thus, most of the current will flow through `RG58` and a voltage drop across `R3` will not be the same with before connecting `RG58`. Is it right?

Comment: What is on the other end of the coax cable?

Comment: A daughterboard of USRP. Specifically, [LFRX](http://www.ettus.com/product/details/LFRX).

Comment: It doesn't say what its input impedance is, but it's probably 50 ohms. Take it off and the voltage drop will go away. *That* is where your impedance problem is, nothing to do with the cable. You need either a high-impedance ADC input or a transimpedance amplifier on the near end of the cable.

Comment: Would voltage follower with op-amp do some help?

Comment: Probably. Although transimpedance is a specific configuration: http://electronicdesign.com/analog/whats-all-transimpedance-amplifier-stuff-anyhow-part-1

Comment: RG58 is a cable, a piece of wire.  The BNC connector by itself is an open circuit.  Neither will have any effect on your under 10 kHz signal.  Either the coax/BNC is shorted, or whatever you connect the BNC connector to has an extremely low impedance.  And since R3 is in parallel with your BNC connector, the voltage drop across both is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think my theory in the comment is right.

I've replaced `R3` with one of 51 ohm and got the following:

[image]

And when I connect `RG58`, I got the following:

[image]

The amplitude has been reduced by 1/2 or something...

It seems that `R3` and `RG58` are connected in parallel, so the total impedance is halved. And so is voltage readings.

Now the problem is, there are lots of noise so it looks quite ugly. So what I want to do and have to do is to put a larger resistance and to make the current flow only through `R3`...

I will search for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using the BNC in this way--what are you hoping to accomplish with it? A BNC cable is NOT equivalent to a 50 ohm resistor, as you seem to think it is. If you look at both ends on a multimeter, you'd see zero ohms dc resistance. So, you are shorting your signal to ground, which is why the voltage disappears across R3. This has nothing to do with impedance matching.

The bnc has 50 ohms *characteristic impedance*. It is not a 50ohm resistor.

Comment: Well, there might be confusion between resistance and impednace, sorry. But, I don't think that it's shorting the signal. Beacuse I got amplitude of 4 mV with R3 = 50 without connecting BNC and amplitude of ~1.4 mV with connecting BNC.

Comment: You know, you can just measure the resistance at least with an multimeter, and eliminate the speculation.  Your input frequency is pretty low to have to worry about transmission line characteristics.

Comment: In the short term, a piece of cable does look pretty much like a resistor to ground.  In the long term (which apparently applies here) you can see what is at the other end, which is presumably a 50 ohm input impedance.  Depending on the form of that it may or may not be 50 resistive ohms to ground at DC.